# How to decouple NSFetchedResultsController from a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I may be overthinking this here.  But here is my overall architecture for my app:

```
NIB-->UITableViewController-->TweetsService-->TweetEntities (in core data)
```

My UITableViewController asks my TweetsService for all of the tweets, and the TweetsService gives back the array of Tweets to my UITableViewController, no questions asked.  It is the TweetsService that talks to core data, and nothing else.

If I add in an NSFetchedResultsController, doesn't that make my UITableViewController bypass my TweetsService?  Is this architecturally correct?  Should I re-route NSFetchedResultsController to go through my TweetsService?  I don't see how I'd do that, though.  Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` is effectively your data source, so rather than your `UITableViewDataSource` asking the `NSArray` your `TweetsService` vends for specific things (count, cellForIndex, etc...), it would ask the instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` these things. You could definitely make your `TweetsService` vend an `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: Thanks, treated NSFetchedResultsController as a datasource is the insight I needed.